# Scrolltop Prev and Next not working in IE or FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get this page to go to the next and previous section with one scroll on the mouse wheel. It works going to the next section, but it fails to go to the previous section. It only happens in IE 9/10 and FF. Works in chrome, IE8, Opera, and Safari. Please help!

My code below:

```
  $(function () {       
    $('section').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
      if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
        $('body, html')
          .stop()
          .animate({scrollTop: $(this).prev().offset().top}, 800, 'easeInOutExpo');
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
       $('body, html')
         .stop()
         .animate({scrollTop: $(this).next().offset().top}, 800, 'easeInOutExpo');
       e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you throwing any errors in console (f12 in ie, right click - inspect element - console in ff)

Comment: Have you tried specifying a selector in `prev()` and `next()` like: `$(this).prev("section")` in case FF & IE are grabbing an unwanted node

Comment: you also have 2 closing brackets `});' in your code... if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Just to let you know in case you find it useful: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this to get `delta`:

```
// cross-browser wheel delta
e = window.event || e;
var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1,(e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

//scrolling down?
if (delta < 0) {

}
//scrolling up
else{

}
```